# Does Frozen Heart affect the Attack Speed from minions/jungle creeps?

Tags: league-of-legends

Well, like the title says: Is the AS from minions and/or the jungle creeps affected by the 25% reduced AS? 
Or does it only affect enemy champions?

Answer (score 6):

If you take a look at [this](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1810078) thread on the LoL page they discuss this matter. It would appear that yes it does affect minion and jungle attack speed. Also, if you look at the description of the Unique on [Frozen Heart](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Frozen_Heart) it says "Unique: Nearby **enemies** suffer −20% attack speed. (1000 range)" Any item that only effects Champions will say it specifically such as [Aegis of the Legion](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Aegis_of_the_Legion).

Aegis of the Legion actually used to affect minions, but they removed that because it was kind of OP. Think about Yorick's minions with the Aegis buff! Terrifying.

Comment: Yorick's minions are not why they changed Aegis. Aegis used to give extra attack damage (+8 I think) as well as defensive buffs, so aegis + large minion wave = minion wave from hell.